# Display MatCalendar using an anchor click

Tags: angular, angular-material

how do I open a Material Calendar component using an anchor element?
I almost did, but the calendar always opens in top left corner of the page:

```
    <li>
      <mat-calendar class="hidden">
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" />
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-calendar>
      <a (click)="picker.open()">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Where do you want the `mat-datepicker` to open? The date-picker is attached to the `input` and opens where the `input` is.

Comment: @fridoo, I got hidding the input inside a div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some headache, I got a solution for this:

```
    <li>
      <div class="hidden-control">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" (dateChange)="scheduleDateChange($event)" />
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <a (click)="picker.open()">
          <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar text-white"></i>
      </a>
    </li>
```

the hidden-control class is like below:

```
.hidden-control  {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

The result:

[image: Opening calendar from anchor]