# How do you make a mat-menu-item call date picker range in Angular without the input field, or date picker icon showing up?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, datepicker

```
.....
<a mat-menu-item (click)="picker.open()"> Date Picker </a>
</met-menu>

<mat-date-range-input [rangePicket]="picker"></mat-date-range-input>
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>
```

but the datepicker just opens very far away from the menu item, and then it also has a "calendar" like button next to it. All I want is when the menu item "Date Picker" is clicked, the calendar with date picker range to show up without input, or the calendar button

Comment: you may follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54905955/5958526